# Python - overriding inherited singleton class method

Tags: python, inheritance, singleton

I was trying to override a method inherited from a singleton class, but it wasn't getting overridden as I expected. please help me fix what I missed here!

```
class SuperParent():
    _instance = None


class SingletonParent(SuperParent):
    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        if SingletonParent._instance is None:
            SingletonParent()
        return SingletonParent._instance

    def __init__(self):
        if SingletonParent._instance is not None:
            raise RuntimeError('Use get_instance()')
        SingletonParent._instance = self

    def print_hi(self):
        print("Hi from SingletonParent")


class SingletonChild(SingletonParent):
    def print_hi(self):
        print("Hi from SingletonChild")
```

When I initialize SingletonChild and call method 'print_hi', it print from SingletonParent, not from the overrided method in SingletonChild.

```
singleton_child = SingletonChild.get_instance()
singleton_child.print_hi()
```

> Hi from SingletonParent

Comment: `get_instance` can only create an instance of `SingletonParent`, not `SingletonChild`. Do you really only want a *single* instance across all classes, or do you want to allow a single instance of `SingletonParent`, and a single instance of `SingletonChild`, etc.?

Comment: I would recommend making `get_instance` a class method (so that it can create an instance of whatever class invokes it), but then you will still be limited to creating an instance of whichever class uses it first, rather than one instance per class. It's not clear that having `SuperParent` track a *single* instance is what you want. Probably each class should have its own `_instance` attribute (which `get_instance` can create  as necessary).

Comment: Also, if `__init__` gets called, you've *already* created a second instance of the class. Override `__new__` instead to prevent the unnecessary instance from being created in the first place.